# With this minor change in the way of solution can't solve all the test cases (0-1 knapsack problem)

Tags: dynamic-programming, knapsack-problem

I was doing 0-1 knapsack problem with the help of dp but when I make a slight change in the code, I get a wrong answer in certain text cases - can't figure out why and I can't figure out how my logic is change with code - can anyone help me?

This is the code of wrong answer

```
int solve(int w, int wt[], int val[], int ans, int i, int n, vector<vector<int>>&dp) {

    if (i >= n)
        return ans;
    
    if (dp[i][w] != -1)
    {
        return dp[i][w];
    }

    int b = 0;
    int a = solve(w, wt, val, ans, i + 1, n, dp);
    // debug(a)

    if (w - wt[i] >= 0)
        b = solve(w - wt[i], wt, val, ans + val[i], i + 1, n, dp);

    // debug(b)
    dp[i][w] = max(a, b);
    return dp[i][w];
}
```

This is the code for the right answer:

```
int solve(int w, int wt[], int val[], int ans, int i, int n, vector<vector<int>>&dp) {

    if (i >= n)
        return 0;
    
    if (dp[i][w] != -1)
    {
        return dp[i][w];
    }

    int b = 0;
    int a = solve(w, wt, val, ans, i + 1, n, dp);
    // debug(a)

    if (w - wt[i] >= 0)
        b = val[i]+solve(w - wt[i], wt, val, ans + val[i], i + 1, n, dp);

    // debug(b)
    dp[i][w] = max(a, b);
    return dp[i][w];
}

//Function to return max value that can be put in knapsack of capacity W.
int knapSack(int W, int wt[], int val[], int n) 
{ 
    // Your code here
    vector<vector<int>>z(n + 1, vector<int>(W + 1, -1));

    return solve(W,wt,val,0,0,n,z);
}
```

p.s if you can figure out the differences see the value of b